# TabWidget text not visible after background color changes

Tags: android, tabwidget, tabview

This works fine for all OS's except Jelly Bean.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("One"),
            Tab1.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Two"),
            Tab2.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Three"),
            Tab3.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("Four"),
            Tab4.class, null);

    TabWidget mTabWidget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();

    mTabWidget.setStripEnabled(false);

    for(int i=0; i < mTabWidget.getChildCount(); i++){
        View v = mTabWidget.getChildAt(i);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector); 
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Background Resource:

```
 `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!--  Active tab -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
<!--  Inactive tab -->
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
<!--  Pressed tab -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<!--  Selected tab -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

`

Nothing crazy here... So why does Jelly Bean display the active tab with only a white background and no text? The inactive tabs display the proper color and text.

Comment: Have you tried settings the android:textColor property to something else?

Comment: I handle the text coloring in styles.xml and this is a non-issue in other os's. This actually affects 4.0 ICS as well...